# Sorting output of treeList finder

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-4.x

Is it possible to sort the output of treeList?

```
$orgUnits = $this->OrganizationalUnits->find('treeList', [
        'keyPath' => 'id', 
        'valuePath' => 'name_en', 
        'spacer' => '-'])
    ->order(['name_en']);
```

Under the same level, they're not coming out sorted. In my test case, I have 3 entries: one starting with b, t and a respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to override the order set by the finder, as it defaults to ordering on `lft`, which is a unique value, so no sub-ordering by other fields would be possible.

You can do so via the `order()` method's second argument:

```php
order(['name_en'], true)
```

or

```php
order(['name_en'], \Cake\ORM\Query::OVERWRITE)
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Query Builder > Ordering Results](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/query-builder.html#ordering-results)**